# React-native NavBottom Design Background

Tags: react-native

Folks I am following a design that have:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT7hQ.jpg) and the bottom navbar have that unique background, I am wondering how to  make it in react native or what exactly is that background name?
The difficulties are: getting the background to be like the design
what I accomplished  are: getting design right until bottom navbar
my question: how to make it in RN or where can I search for a solution?
Thanks in advance !

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="home"
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor:
        "radial-gradient(circle, rgba(6,12,28,1) 0%, rgba(121,164,193,1) 53%, rgba(177,207,240,1) 100%)",
      position: "absolute",
      elevation: 0,
      opacity: 0.9,
      height: heightscale(70),
      alignItems: "center",
      borderRadius: 20,
      shadowColor: "#000",
      bottom: heightscale(20),
      padding: moderateScale(10),
      justifyContent: "center",
      marginHorizontal: moderateScale(20),
    },
  }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="home"
    component={Home}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {focused ? (
            <Homeiconsolid size={30} color={"#2683f1"} />
          ) : (
            <HomeIcon size={30} color={focused ? "#2683f1" : "#748c94"} />
          )}
        </View>
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Search"
    component={Search}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {focused ? (
            <Searchiconsolid size={30} color={"#2683f1"} />
          ) : (
            <MagnifyingGlassIcon
              size={30}
              color={focused ? "#2683f1" : "#748c94"}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Favorite"
    component={Bookmark}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {focused ? (
            <Bookmarkiconsolid
              size={30}
              color={focused ? "#2683f1" : "#748c94"}
            />
          ) : (
            <BookmarkIcon size={30} color={focused ? "#2683f1" : "#748c94"} />
          )}
        </View>
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Profile}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {focused ? (
            <Usericonsolid size={30} color={"#2683f1"} />
          ) : (
            <UserIcon size={30} color={focused ? "#2683f1" : "#748c94"} />
          )}
        </View>
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blurry effect in the bottom navigation bar can be achieved by using a package `@react-native-community/blur`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/blur

I was able to achieve it in one of my projects and it looks like this in action.

[image]

*Note: This package can not be applied directly to your Tab navigation.*

To be able to use this package, you need to create a main screen which will render other screens on state change and hide them if the state returns false.

```
<View>
  {screenSelection?.home === true ? <Home /> : null}

  {screenSelection?.goal === true ? <Goals /> : null}

  {screenSelection?.account === true ? <Account /> : null}

  {screenSelection?.notification === true ? <Notifications /> : null}
</View>
```

To add the blur effect to your screen, use `BlurView` like this,

```
<View style={styles.bottomBarStyle}>
  <BlurView
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
    }}
    blurType="light"
    blurAmount={6}
    reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
  />

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles?.bottomTabStyle}
    onPress={() => handleScreenSelection("home")}
  >
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      source={
        screenSelection?.home === true
          ? require("../../images/home_selected.png")
          : require("../../images/home_faded.png")
      }
    />       
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles?.bottomTabStyle}
    onPress={() => handleScreenSelection("target")}
  >
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      source={
        screenSelection?.goal === true
          ? require("../../images/target_selected.png")
          : require("../../images/target_faded.png")
      }
    />       
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles?.bottomTabStyle}
    onPress={() => handleScreenSelection("notification")}
  >        
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      source={
        screenSelection?.notification === true
          ? require("../../images/bell_selected.png")
          : require("../../images/bell_faded.png")
      }
    />    
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles?.bottomTabStyle}
    onPress={() => handleScreenSelection("account")}
  >
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      source={
        screenSelection?.account === true
          ? require("../../images/profile_selected.png")
          : require("../../images/profile_faded.png")
      }
    />        
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>;
```

Everything above the `BlurView` will be blurred, so we will create a view and provide styling to it according to the UI design. Components below the `BlurView` will be rendered correctly over the blurred component.